# Angular 1.5 Unit Testing Directive ng-include Template

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I'm trying to test UI state of a directive that dynamically loads templates via ng-include. I was having issues with the element being undefined and after googling the fix was to simply wrap the compiled element with a parent html element i.e, div. This resolved the undefined element issue but now the element is defined as the comment node instead of the rendered template.

**directive**

```
function myDirective(
  return {
    scope: {
      tpl: '@'
    },
    template: '<ng-include src="template"/>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      if(scope.tpl == 'view') {
        scope.template = 'app/view.tpl.html';
      }
      if(scope.tpl == 'edit') {
        scope.template = 'app/edit.tpl.html';
      }
```

**parent template of directive**

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.myStuff track by $index" tpl="edit">
</my-directive>
```

**spec**

```
describe('myDirective', function() {
  var $rootScope, $compile, element, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
    $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
    $compile = $injector.get("$compile");
    element = angular.element('<div><my-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.myStuff track by $index" tpl="edit"></my-directive></div>');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // wrap scope changes using $apply
    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.template = 'app/edit.tpl.html';
      scope.vm = {
        myStuff: [{}, {}]
      };
      $compile(element)(scope);
    });
  }));
  it("edit template save button should be displayed", function() {
    console.log(element.html());
    '<!-- ngRepeat: item in vm.myStuff track by $index -->'
  });
});
```

**output after adding myStuff array**

```
<div>
  <!-- ngRepeat: item in vm.myStuff track by $index -->
      <!-- ngIf: !$last && item -->
        <my-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.myStuff track by $index" tpl="edit"> 
        </my-directive>
      <!-- end ngIf: !$last && widget -->
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in vm.myStuff track by $index -->

      <!-- ngIf: !$last && item -->
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in vm.myStuff track by $index -->
</div>
```

### UPDATE

I added the data for `ng-repeat` but now see the commented directive but not the rendered `edit.tpl.html` template.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` directive needs data:

```
  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
    $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
    $compile = $injector.get("$compile");
    element = angular.element('<div><my-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.myStuff track by $index" tpl="edit"></my-directive></div>');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // wrap scope changes using $apply
    scope.$apply(function() {
      //INIT vm.myStuff
      scope.vm = {myStuff: ["item1"]};
      //
      scope.template = 'app/edit.tpl.html';
      $compile(element)(scope);
    });
  }));
```

The `ng-repeat="item in vm.myStuff` directive converts the element to a comment node. It only adds elements when there is data.

Comment: That makes sense. I added the data for ng-repeat but now see the commented directive but not the rendered edit.tpl.html  template.

Comment: Looks like a "Russian Doll" problem. Fix one problem, lift the doll, find another problem.